# AngularFire2 error 'Cannot read property'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

the Angular4 app I'm working on displays the currently playing song in the header. to do so I'm using a firbase observable in a playlist service and returning the resulting "noePlaying" object to the header component at OnInit, at which point it is subscribed to and stored in that component. I'm displaying the result in the view, but even though it's showing, my console shows an error:
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined 
-the error points to the OnInit function in my header component. 
-I get a similar error when I use the play() function, which changes the nowPlaying song
"Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property '$key' of undefined"

Can anyone please help me figure this out? The app seems to functioning as should but the errors indicate that I must be doing something improperly. Thank you! Below is the code for the Playlist service, the Header Component TS, and the Header Component HTML.

Playlist Service

```js
import {  Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Song } from './song.model';

import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class PlaylistService {

user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  songs: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  sizeSubject: Subject<any>;
  nowPlaying: FirebaseListObservable<Song>;
  np: any;
  npKey: any;


  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {};


 getSongs(){

    this.songs = this.db.list('/songs', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'likes',  
      }
  }
    ).map((array) => array.reverse())  as FirebaseListObservable<Song[]>;


  return this.songs;
 }
  
  getNowPlaying(){

 this.nowPlaying = this.db.list('/songs', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'play',
        equalTo: 1
      }
  })  as FirebaseListObservable<Song>      

    return this.nowPlaying;
  }
 


play(nextSongKey, currentSongKey){

  this.songs.update(currentSongKey,{ play: 0 });
  this.songs.update(nextSongKey,{ play: 1 });
    // console.log(typeof nextSongKey);
    // console.log( typeof currentSongKey);

}

stop(id){
  this.songs.update(id,{ play: 0 });
}






}
```

Admin Component HTML

```html
<div class="tablediv">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Likes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let song of songs | filter: term ; let i  = index"

    [style.backgroundColor]="song.play == 1? 'skyblue' : 'transparent'"
  >

  <!--|  sortBy: 'likes'-->

<td >{{ song.title }}</td>
<td >{{ song.artist }}</td>
<td  [style.min-width]="'200px'" >{{ song.likes }}
 
            <i class="fa fa-play" [class.hidden]="song.play == 1" (click)="play(song.$key)" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          
   
    
</td>

  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Admin Component TS

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule,AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { PlaylistService } from '../playlist.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

user: Observable<firebase.User>;
songs: any;
CurrentSongKey: any;
term: string = '';


  constructor(private plService: PlaylistService,
              public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
                this.user = afAuth.authState;
              }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.plService.getSongs() .subscribe (songs => { 
     this.songs = songs;
        });   

        this.plService.getNowPlaying()
     .subscribe (nowPlaying => { 
     this.CurrentSongKey = nowPlaying[0]['$key'];
     console.log(this.CurrentSongKey)
        });

  }




removeLike(id: string, likes: number): void {
 this.plService.removeLike(id, likes);
}

play(id) {
  this.plService.play(id, this.CurrentSongKey);
 
}
stop(id){
  this.plService.stop(id);
}


  


}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `{{nowPlaying?.title}}` and all others that have an object with property paths. This seems to be an async issue.

Comment: As @AJT_82 mentioned, this is an `async` issue. When you assign `title` to `this.npTitle`, `nowPlaying` isn't resolved yet. Why don't you assign it directly in your subscription? E.g. `this.npTitle = nowPlaying[0]['title'];`

Comment: @AJT_82 Thank you! Your solution worked perfectly. However, the play function still seems to be showing errors..its says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined" and "WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property '$key' of undefined" The function doesn't work at all when I click it the first time, but the works the second time I click it and from then on... I don't think I can add question marks in TS  functions, so what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: @AJT_82 Thank you!. I read your links and implemented your suggestions. (code above edited to show changes) However, I’m still getting errors on the play function.
'Cannot read property '$key' of undefined'

It works the first time, but when I click it a second time, the next song plays but the previous song doesn’t stop, so it looks like they’re both playing... maybe because the currentSongKey value hasn’t been updated, even though I subscribed to it in the component! What’s going on?

Comment: No problem, done! If it helps, you can see an earlier version of the live at http://oxcord.io . It's an app that shows a playlist and lets people vote on which songs get played next. What I'm working on is an admin component where I can play a song (by setting song.play = 1), while simultaneously stopping the previous song (setting song.play = 0). The play function is activated on an icon in the html (click), and then the component calls the function from the service, passing the currently playing song's $key and the key (id) of new song to be played (the one clicked) as aguments.

Comment: OK I'll spend some time today to learn how to use plunker :S...In the mean time, to answer your questions 1. The nowPlaying in the component subscribes to the observable  from the playlist service. It also takes the key of that song (nowPlaying[0]['$key']) and stores it as CurrentSongKey for the play function to use (it will set the play property of this song to 0 when called). 2. I think that's where the problem is, I assumed that the CurrenSongKey value would update automatically after changing the song, since it's set in a subscription, but it doesn't seem to do so.

Comment: If you mean that it would update since it's in OnInit. No, it does not do that, you need to separately call it again to get the current key. And as for the plunker, what I meant with my plunker was just to showcase about which amount of code is needed to reproduce the issue, which is not much as you can see in plunker :)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to move this to chat yet so I guess I'll answer here. I cleaned up my code a bit more and removed the header snippets, since that part is no longer a problem :) I'm confused, isn't the whole point of a subscription to provide data asynchronously...Why won't the value from the subscription in ngOninit keep updating afterwards? And if that's the case, does that mean I should subscribe again each time I want the updated value?

Comment: By the way, how come you didn't answer instead of just comment? I would have loved to mark your answer as Accepted, since it solved my problem!

Comment: Yeah I can't start a chat either, seems the other party needs 20 rep as well.  Just cleaned some comments, as they are not relevant anymore when you have edited question. To answer, how would Angular know when to subscribe in this scenario? :) How often?

Comment: From what I understood, the function in ngOnit starts the subscription, and that subscription stays open, updating the data automatically every time the observable data changes (because the observable emits next() when something changes)... all the way until the component is destroyed. I thought that's how it worked because every time I change the Now Playing Song in the database, it updated in the header automatically. Did I misunderstand?